# Azure AD JWT Token Validation options

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

In the [Microsoft Azure AD Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens) the JWT Token validation process is described as validating the token signature and then validating its claims.

So, the validation happens entirely on the client side, without asking the Azure AD server whether the token is still valid.

Is there any option for "extended" validation of the token, i.e. by querying for the Azure server, so that the application granting the access to the resource could be sure that the person is still authorized and has an access to that resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, access is granted for the lifetime of the token.

Tokens have an expiration date that you can read from the `exp` claim.  You can control the expiration of a token which then requires the user to reauthenticate after expiration.

If you want to do extended validation, you will need to implement that logic.

[ID Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens)

[Access Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens)

[Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the following scenario: 1. The user is authenticated via AAD, 2. The user is removed from the AAD 3. The user tries to access a protected resource with the token received at the step 1

The protected resource would give the information, since the token still hasn't expired (even though it is revoked) ?

Comment: Access and Identity Tokens are not revoked in Azure AAD. They only expire. Refresh Tokens can be revoked. Yes, the service will consider the token valid. You have a tradeoff between authorization lifetime and re-authenticating. Tokens are expensive to perform extensive validation upon. That is one reason they are signed and have a lifetime - to speed up processing as some APIs use tokens for every call which would dramatically slow down network response times. Another factor is that revoking a token is a slow operation to sync in global networks/services.

Comment: If you want, you can of course query the Graph API for user existence and sign in enable status, but that comes at a significant throughput cost.

Comment: Thank you for comments. What if I'd like to verify the user's access just before performing some critical operation? What Graph API should I call in that case?

How about Single Log Out, can the Application Server somehow get the information that the user has been removed?

Comment: @RichardTopchiy - Create a new question as that is more complicated then will fit in a comment. Try to think about the security implications of granting Active Directory access to an application that should not have it. In some cases your solution is more expensive/risky then the problem. Just use shorter token lifetimes.